# I'm losing my connection session to the client. Response.IsClientConnected returns false

Tags: jquery, vb.net, wcf

Client javascript calls aspx.vb. VB code behind which then calls a WCF data contract that returns data from an SQL data base. That data is then serialized and inserted into a response.write() method.

It fails. No exceptions, no errors, nothing.

After the WCF HTTPS call, the response.isClientConnected property is getting set to 'false'. Making the HTTPS call to the WCF service is making the response.write lose it's connection to the client that called it.

Any ideas to get around this?  Perhaps something different than
 response.write() ?

What I have tried:

1 -  I have taken the data returned from the WCF call, and pasted it as a string in the response.write("").

```
  If I then comment out the WCF HTTPS call, it works fine.
```

2 - I've tried moving the function that calls the WCF out of the aspx.vb that has the response.write.  No change.

Thanks

Comment: How do you do the WCF HTTPS call?

Comment: I actually don't know much about WCF.  Another guy wrote the WCF part.  But I do know it's called a channel contract.